# Selenium WebDriver how to verify Text from Span Tag in javascript

Tags: javascript, selenium

I'm not able to get value from the span tag as below:

```
var error = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('error-container-text')).getAttribute('innerHTML');
```

but this is showing something like this -

```
ManagedPromise {
  flow_: 
   ControlFlow {
     propagateUnhandledRejections_: true,
     activeQueue_: 
      TaskQueue {
        name_: 'TaskQueue::216',
        flow_: [Circular],
        tasks_: [Object],
        interrupts_: null,
        pending_: null,
        subQ_: null,
        state_: 'new',
        unhandledRejections_: Set {} },
     taskQueues_: Set { [Object] },
     shutdownTask_: null,
     hold_: 
      Timeout {
        _called: false,
        _idleTimeout: 2147483647,
        _idlePrev: [Object],
        _idleNext: [Object],
        _idleStart: 22977,
        _onTimeout: [Function],
        _timerArgs: undefined,
        _repeat: 2147483647 } },
  stack_: 
   { Task: WebElement.getAttribute(innerHTML)
       at thenableWebDriverProxy.schedule (/home/app/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:816:17)
       at WebElementPromise.schedule_ (/home/app/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:2024:25)
       at WebElementPromise.getAttribute (/home/app/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:2276:17)
       at Context.<anonymous> (/home/app/PycharmProjects/SampleTest/Sample.js:72:85)
       at runTest (/home/app/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/testing/index.js:164:22)
       at /home/app/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/testing/index.js:185:16
       at new ManagedPromise (/home/app/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1085:7)
       at controlFlowExecute (/home/app/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/testing/index.js:184:14)
       at TaskQueue.execute_ (/home/app/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:3092:14)
       at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (/home/app/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:3075:27)
       at asyncRun (/home/app/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2982:25)
       at /home/app/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:676:7 name: 'Task' },
  parent_: null,
  callbacks_: null,
  state_: 'pending',
  handled_: false,
  value_: undefined,
  queue_: null }
```

Comment: What SPAN tag are you referring to? Please post the relevant HTML and add more specifics to your scenario. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable error-container ng-scope" id="errorContainer" ng-if="errorMessage">
    <button type="button" class="close" ng click="closeErrorMesssage()">×</button>
    <span class="error-container-text ng-binding" id="error-container-text">User ID cannot be left blank</span>
  </div>                                                                                                                 This is the HTML, I need span's text from here.

Comment: But if I am adding textContent, it is showing undefined.

Comment: Please edit and update your question with the relevant HTML and details of what you have tried and the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using below:

```
 var error = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('error-container-text')).getAttribute('innerHTML'):
```

Comment: innerHTML and textContent are not the same thing.

Comment: textContent is the JS equivalent of `.getText()` in Java or `.Text` in C#. innerHTML retrieves the HTML content of the specified element. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML.

Comment: @kushal textContent again is showing the same thing, not getting the text of that span.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that also. But it is not working. As from my understanding, .getText() is a function of Java and I am using Javascript.

Comment: Can you post some HTML for the same?

Comment: <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable error-container ng-scope" id="errorContainer" ng-if="errorMessage"> <button type="button" class="close" ng click="closeErrorMesssage()">×</button> <span class="error-container-text ng-binding" id="error-container-text">User ID cannot be left blank</span> </div> This is the HTML, I need span's text from here.

Comment: Or better yet try .getAttribute("outerHTML"); and share the results.

Comment: undefined value same as before , no change.

Comment: Okay as you have been using id to identify this now try using css selector for the same as `By.cssSelector("div#errorContainer span").getAttribute("innerHTML");` also add a delay of 5 seconds before this statement

Comment: because the code contains angularjs binding; sometimes it may take time to load

Comment: Still facing the same issue.

Comment: Yes, I have added sleep function and tried all the suggestions, getting same undefined value in each case.

Comment: One last thing try `.getAttribute("innerText");`